# Group results by period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some data which I want to retrieve, but I want to have it grouped by a specific number of seconds. For example if my table looks like this:

```
| id | user | pass | created |
```

The `created` column is INT and holds a timestamp (number of seconds from 1970).

I would want the number of users that are created between last month and the current date, but show them grouped by let's say `7*24*3600` (a week). So if in the range there are 1000 new users, have them show up how many registered each week (100 the first week, 450 the second, 50 the third and 400 the 4th week -- something like this).

I've tried grouping the results by `created / 7*24*3600`, but that's not working.

How should my query look like?

Comment: What kind of column is `created`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it. It is INT, and it holds a timestamp in seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use integer division `div` otherwise the result will turn into a real and none of the weeks will resolve to the same value.

```
SELECT 
  (created div (7*24*60*60)) as weeknumber
  , count(*) as NewUserCount
FROM users
WHERE weeknumber > 1
GROUP BY weeknumber
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html

Comment: Thanks, your solution has provided me with an important information: `div`

Comment: +1 But take into account that `div` is mysql-specific syntax. The same could be achieved using the SQL2003 Standard function `floor()`.

Comment: @XaviLópez, in SQL-server the `/` operator returns a trucated integer if both operand are integers.

Answer (score 2):

You've got to keep the integer part only of that division. You can do it with the `floor()` function.

Have you tried `select floor(created/604800) as week_no, count(*) from users group by floor(created/604800)` ?

I assume you've got the "select users created in the last month" part sorted out.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that I was using the `/` operator to do divisions, instead of `div`. But the main idea is something like your query.

Answer (score 1):

Okay here are the possible options you may try:

**GROUP BY DAY**

```
select count(*), DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d") as created_day FROM widgets GROUP BY created_day
```

**GROUP BY MONTH**

```
select count(*), DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m") as created_month FROM widgets GROUP BY created_month
```

**GROUP BY YEAR**

```
select count(*), DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y") as created_year FROM widgets GROUP BY created_year
```